# What is the probability that a team wins at least x times in a row, at least y times?

Tags: probability, statistics

Say a team plays 82 games in a season and won 65 of 82 games. From here I take this as the probability of a win at any point in the season. I would like to determine the probability that a team wins at least 6 games in a row, at least 3 times. My idea was to do $p_{1} = 1-Binomial(p=\frac{65}{82},n=82,k=6)$ for the probability the team wins 6 games in a row. I then thought that using 1 - Binomial CDF again but with $p = p_{1}$ and $k = 3$ would get me the probability there was at least 3 win streaks of length 6 (or greater). The issue is that I am not sure what n would be in the CDF. I thought n could be how many times a team plays 6 games in a row, but a team plays 6 games in a row starting from game 1, 2, etc. A win streak of 6 could occur starting from any one of those games. Would I use $n = 77$, because that is the last game a team could start a 6 game win streak? Or is using Binomial here incorrect? Any help would be much appreciated. My last statistics course was around 4 years ago.

Edit: Winning more than 6 games in a row counts as only one event of 6 consecutive wins. Each streak of consecutive wins must be made up of a disjoint set of games.

Edit:

```
def sim(games: list, n: int):
    # real denotes number of times a team won n or more games in a row
    # count_consec_w counts the number of times a team won (n+i) games in a row
    real = sum([count_consec_w(games, n+i) for i in range(25)])
    count = 0
    games_copy = copy.deepcopy(games)
    for i in range(10000):
        random.shuffle(games_copy)
        sim = sum([count_runs(games_copy, n+i) for i in range(25)])
        # if the simulated season has at least as many occurrences of the team winning n or more
        # games in a row, count += 1
        if sim >= real:
            count += 1

    return count / 10000
```

I simulated the probability of this event and found 0.9234. I was hoping to find a way to calculate the probability using a distribution or formula so that I can check how close the two estimates are to one another.

Comment: If a team wins 8 in a row, is that winning 6 in a row three times (starting on the first, starting on the second, and starting on the third win)?

Comment: It seems like this is a combinatorial problem.  There are $\binom{82}{17}$ ways to distribute the $17$ losses throughout the season.  How many of those ways yield at least three $6$-game winning streaks?  Please do clarify whether the winning streaks can overlap or whether they need to comprise disjoint games.  I'm framing it as a combinatorial problem because if the team had won $81$ of its $82$ games, it would be a certainty that it had at least three disjoint $6$-game winning streaks, but a probabilistic approach would yield a probability somewhat less than $1$.

Comment: @RobertShore There is a a question of whether the $\binom{82}{65}$ patterns are equally likely. Perhaps a team has periods when it is playing well and with confidence and other times when not.  Or perhaps it is more likely to win at home rather than away/on-the-road

Comment: If you allow overlaps of the $6$ wins-in-a-row and if you assume the $\binom{82}{65}$ patterns are equally likely then, although the distribution is not binomial, you can at least find the expected number, which is $(82-6+1)\times\frac{65 \times 64\times63\times62\times61\times60}{82 \times 81\times80\times79\times78\times77}$ $\approx 18.16$. The probability that a team has $6$ wins-in-a-row at least $3$ times is going to be high.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Winning 8 in a row would count as only one win streak of 6. I should have clarified that.

Comment: @Henry I edited my post to clarify overlaps are not allowed. Of course the probability of the team winning each game is different because of the factors you mentioned, among others, but I wish to simplify the problem. I only need a simple theoretical probability.

Comment: @sla813 It is not simple, and not allowing overlaps makes it even harder

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you require the sets of $6$ to be disjoint, take three groups of six, place each group between any two losses or on the end (they can both be placed at the same position). Then place the rest of the wins anywhere you like (outside of the groups). I believe the number of ways of doing this is ${(47+3)+18-1 \choose 18-1}$ and the probability is $\frac{{(47+3)+18-1 \choose 18-1}}{{65+18-1 \choose 18-1}}\approx0.02$ which seems rather small. Perhaps someone can correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: By Henry's post I can see this is wrong but don't know where it's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simulation of $10^5$ runs in R, suggesting the probability may be over $0.996$ in the non-overlap case (changing `overlaps=FALSE` to `overlaps=TRUE` suggests over $0.9999$ when overlaps are counted):

```
simstreaks <- function(games, wins, inarow, overlaps){
  winloss <- sample(c(rep(1, wins),rep(0, games-wins)), games)
  gamessofar <- inarow
  numberstreaks <- 0
  while (gamessofar <= games){
    if (sum(winloss[(gamessofar - inarow + 1):gamessofar]) == inarow){
      numberstreaks <- numberstreaks + 1
      gamessofar <- gamessofar + (1-overlaps)*(inarow-1)
      }
    gamessofar <- gamessofar + 1
    }
  numberstreaks 
  }

set.seed(2023)
sims <- replicate(10^5, simstreaks(games=82, wins=65, inarow=6, overlaps=FALSE))     

table(sims)
# sims
#  1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9 
# 15   328  3821 17613 35505 30892 10493  1292    41 

mean(sims)
# 5.29619
 
mean(sims >= 3)
# 0.99657
```

Comment: I edited my post to include the code I wrote originally to estimate the probability of this event. Do you think there is a way to calculate the probability using a common distribution or several distributions?